# Is there a way to show the next element in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to click a button and have it print out the next element in an array. I only want it to show the next element each time you press the button.

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three"]

@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
     print(array[1])    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a counter and use modulo:

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three"]
var counter = 0

@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
     print(array[counter % array.count])
     counter += 1
}
```

Comment: You do not want the `- 1`

Comment: and you meant `array.count`. Btw it is Swift naming convention to name your methods starting with a lowercase letter

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can get the `next` item from an array it to make an `Iterator`.  This is useful if you want an exhaustible supply of values.

For example:

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three"]
var iterator = array.makeIterator()

if let value = iterator.next() {
    print(value)
}
```

> ```
> one
> ```

```
if let value = iterator.next() {
    print(value)
}
```

> ```
> two
> ```

```
if let value = iterator.next() {
    print(value)
}
```

> ```
> three
> ```

Once the `Iterator` is out of values, it returns `nil`:

```
if let value = iterator.next() {
    print(value)
} else {
    print("out of values")
}
```

> ```
> out of values
> ```

You can also use an `Iterator` in a `for-in` loop:

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three"]
var iterator = array.makeIterator()

for value in iterator {
    print(value)
}
```

> ```
> one
> two
> three
> ```

You can convert the remaining items into an `Array`:

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three"]

var iterator = array.makeIterator()
let first = iterator.next()!

let rest = Array(iterator)
print(first)
print(rest)
```

> ```
> one
> ["two", "three"]
> ```